# Laravel Query Builder get data from other table under certain condition

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

Good day, I'm trying to get specific products from a different table.
This is my **products table**:

[image]

I also have a table called **banned_products**:

[image]

I have difficulty getting the right data using Laravel Query Builder.
This is what I have so far:

```
    $banned_products = DB::table('banned_products')
        ->select('product_id')
        ->where('reason', '=', 'unknown')
        ->groupBy('product_id');


    return DB::table('products')
        ->leftJoinSub($banned_products, 'banned_products', function ($join) {
            $join->on('products.id', '=', 'banned_products.product_id');
        })
        ->select(
            'products.id as product_id',
            'products.identifier')
        ->whereNull('products.deleted_at')->get();
```

this query returns me all the products but not the deleted one with the reason unknown that I want.

How to do it?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try if the following works?

```
DB::table('products')
->rightJoin('banned_products', 'banned_products.product_id', 'products.id')
->where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('banned_products.reason', 'unknown')
    ->orWhereNull('banned_products.id');
})
->get(['products.id as product_id', 'products.identifier']);

/*
SQL Query:

select
   "products"."id" as "product_id",
   "products"."identifier"
from "products"
right join "banned_products" on "banned_products"."product_id" = "products"."id"
where (
   "banned_products"."reason" = "unknown"
   or "banned_products"."id" is null
)

*/
```

Comment: Hello IGP thank you responding, your query is not returning me the all the products + the banned one with reason = unknown. It does return me the banned product with the other products only if the product reason is not unknown.

Comment: I misread your question. I thought you wanted all the products that weren't banned with reason unknown. It should be the same query but instead of using `whereNotExists`/`whereDoesntHave` use `whereExists`/`whereHas`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response now this way it's returning a null. On the DB query builder it returns me just the banned product with reason unknow, how to get the other products?

Comment: Oh, right. If you only want the deleted product it should be `whereNotNull` instead of `whereNull`.

Comment: This way its returning me the deleted product without the rest of products.

Comment: I totally misunderstood your question then. Your original code should work if you remove the `whereNull`, sorry about the confusion. But if you want all the products, why bother with the join in the first place?

Comment: I want all the products even the deleted ones if their banned reason is unknown.

Comment: What if their banned reason is not unknown?

Comment: They faild validation in txt file for some reason and get banned. I just want  get all products even deleted ones(they get deleted when they are banned), now compare if banned ones have reason unknown add them to the query as well if they have other reason we don't want those.