# Get data from other table in Laravel Query Builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to get data from 2 tables in Laravel Query builder.
Here are the 2 tables I am using:

| relation | administration |
| --- | --- |
| id | id |
| administration_id | name |
| mail |  |
| invoice_mail |  |
| company |  |
| first_name |  |
| last_name |  |

So I want to fill a selectbox with the fields `company`, `first_name`, `last_name` and `administration.name`.

I am trying to get this with following query:

```
$Relations = Relation::where('in_profit','=',1)->where('error_profit','=',null);
$relation_options = [];
$Relations = $Relations
->join('administration', 'administration.id' , '=', 'relation.administration_id')
->select(DB::raw("id,mail, invoice_mail, administration.name, IFNULL(company, CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name)) as fullname, CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) as name"))->get();
$relation_options = $Relations->pluck('fullname','id','administration.name' );
```

But i'm getting a 500 error, I think it has something to do with the join query.

This is the error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous (SQL: select id,mail, invoice_mail, administration.name, IFNULL(company, CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name)) as fullname, CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) as name from `relation` inner join `administration` on `administration`.`id` = `relation`.`administration_id` where `in_profit` = 1 and `error_profit` is null and `relation`.`deleted_at` is null)
```

Thanks already!

Comment: ->select(DB::raw("relation.id,relation.mail") Use something like that

Comment: You should use table alias name or table name when applied join and specially table have same fields on each side

Comment: Is this your answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63076317/12232340